# How to use older version of Dart editor

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Today, when I was trying to run my dart application in Dartium, I was forced to download a new version (r19425) of the Dart Editor + SDK. However this latest version breaks web_ui due to issue https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8979, and my project is using the web_ui package.

Until the issue is fixed I would like to use an older version of the editor/sdk. But how should I do that? If I try to use an older build it just forces me to update it again ...

Answer (score 3):

All the trunk builds (right back to 1141 for nostalgia's sake) are available at this URL:

http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-editor-archive-integration/

Pick your version, download the relevant archive, and unzip somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I still had a couple of old builds on my pc so I could use one of those.
But the problem is, that even when I use an old build, as soon as I try to run my app in Dartium, I can't, because I get the message 'This build has expired. Please download a new Dartium ..'

Answer (score 2):

I've just uploaded 0.4.1+3 for web_ui. Try running "pub update" and let me know if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Great, much better than a workaround! I ran pub update and web_ui is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the auto-update.

Tools->Preferences->Update

Deselect "Download Updates Automatically"

Comment: Thanks, but that setting is already unchecked. The editor is still on the earlier version, however when I try to launch my application in Dartium it gives me the message 'This build has expired. Please download a new Dartium at http://www.dartlang.org/dartium/index.html'.

Comment: you should be able to download a separate standalone Dartium install and go to the relevant url "manually" in that.

Comment: When I start Dartium on its own and paste the url in there, like so: http://127.0.0.1:3030/Users/misja/workspace/backgammon/dartboard/web/out/dartboard.html,
then it doesn't launch my app either but gives me the build expire message again ..

Comment: try creating a build config that does not launch dartium automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The older versions of the stable Dart SDK can be downloaded at http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/release/ . You have to look into the `VERSION` file contained in every folder to see the public version corresponding to the build number used as folder name.

The versions from the *Dev* channel are available at http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/dev/release/ .